# Processing text file and write it content to HTML output

Tags: powershell

Hi all I have written the following code to export the text file content to HTML formatted output, but I am not getting the result as expected can some one help me

```
function TextToHtml {
    $SourceFile = "C:\sample.txt"
    $TargetFile = "C:\TestOutput.htm"

    $TextData = Get-Content $SourceFile

    foreach ($Line in $TextData) {
        $LineData = $FileLine + $Line
    }

    $LineData | ConvertTo-HTML | Out-File $TargetFile
}
```

[image]

Comment: What is stored in `$FileLine` here?

Comment: What output do you expect? What is the content of `sample.txt`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ConvertTo-Html` turns *object properties* into values in a list or table. A string only has one property, `Length` - that's what you see the value of in your output.

Create a new object with `$LineData` as a property value and you'll get meaningful output

```
function TextToHtml
{
    $SourceFile = "C:\sample.txt"
    $TargetFile = "C:\TestOutput.htm"

    $TextData = Get-Content $SourceFile

    Foreach ($Line in $TextData) {
      $LineData = $LineData + $Line
    }
    New-Object psobject -Property @{Text = $LineData} | ConvertTo-HTML -Property Text | Out-File $TargetFile

}
```

To make your function more reusable, turn the source and target file paths into parameters.

You also don't need to iterate over each string in `$TextData` to append them to each other, just use the `-join` operator:

```
function TextToHtml
{
    param(
        [string]$SourceFile = "C:\sample.txt",
        [string]$TargetFile = "C:\TestOutput.htm"
    )

    $TextData = Get-Content $SourceFile

    $LineData = $TextData -join ''

    New-Object psobject -Property @{Text = $LineData} | ConvertTo-HTML | Out-File $TargetFile

}
```

If you want to avoid the `*` header for objects that only have one property, use the `-Property` parameter with `ConvertTo-Html` to explicitly select the `Text` property:

```
ConvertTo-Html -Property Text
```

If you want to show each line in it's own table row, skip the concatenation and pipe the strings directly to `ConvertTo-Html` instead:

```
function TextToHtml
{
    param(
        [string]$SourceFile = "C:\sample.txt",
        [string]$TargetFile = "C:\TestOutput.htm"
    )

    Get-Content $SourceFile | ConvertTo-HTML -Property @{Label='Text';Expression={$_}} | Out-File $TargetFile

}
```

Comment: Hi an astriek symbol is coming how can I over come that, also if I want to display each line tr td format is it possible

Comment: @Learner Updated answer

Comment: Thanks Mathias R. Jessen

Answer (score 0):

If we go just with the code pasted in the question above. It will give you the value of $FileLine (here it is null or blank) and text from last line in that file.

But if you want to have all lines as well use below code:

```
function TextToHtml
{
    $SourceFile = "C:\sample.txt"
    $TargetFile = "C:\TestOutput.htm"
    $TextData = Get-Content $SourceFile

    Foreach ($Line in $TextData) {
      $LineData = $FileLine + $LineData + $Line
    }
   $LineData | ConvertTo-HTML | Out-File $TargetFile

}
```